# compass susy span-columns percentages misscalculated

Tags: grid, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I had this problem briefly with my standard desktop media query sized columns, but it seemed to get resolved on its own. Now that I'm resetting columns for a reduced width media query, the problem has returned for this new implementation. The problem is that when added together, the total percentage widths of my two columns, including margins (I'm not using padding currently), is too large.

In case it matters, I'm using Susy to replace Twitter Bootstrap (sass version) grids. I've removed several redundant Bootstrap files including: _grid.scss, _layouts.scss

My OSX Firefox Inspector shows the following:

```
#main { width: 65.9575%; }
#local { width: 31.9149%; margin-right: 2.12766%; }
```

All together, this equals: 100.00006 - breaking my layout. Thanks in advance! This is a real head scratcher.

My scss is:

```
_variables.scss
===================

// Susy Grids
// -------------------------
$total-columns:                 12;     // 12
$column-width:                  60px;   // 60px
$gutter-width:                  20px;   // 20px
$grid-padding:                  0px;    // $gutter-width


_responsive.scss
===================

@media (max-width: $breakWidthMaxPhoneLandscape) // 768px
{
.page-template-default
    {
        #main,
        #sub,
        #local
        {
            @include reset-columns;
        }

        #main
        {
            @include span-columns(8 omega, $total-columns);
        }

        #local
        {
            @include span-columns(4, $total-columns);
            @include pull(12);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't re-create this from what you've posted. Can you provide a full sample (html+sass) that demonstrates the problem when copy/pasted into a clean project? Also, what browser/version is it breaking on? And at what sizes?

Comment: I'm using OSX Firefox version 21. I'm using Responsive Code View to test at 768x1024. Due to the number of sass files, I've opted to zip everything needed: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72397898/susyTest.zip)

Comment: Interestingly, I just made some mixins of my own to calculate percentage column widths, push and pull amounts, etc. I have the EXACT same error of .00006 too much. I wonder if this is a Sass or Compass issue?

Comment: I haven't yet fixed the .00006 error, but I did get the floats to not break. It turns out some margins weren't being properly overridden. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: That makes more sense. The .00006 isn't really a bug, it's just a bit of rounding - and so small that it should never break a layout in any modern browser.